# Showing a subliminal image on iPad

Tags: ios, performance, ipad, uiimage

While working on an iPad app for researchers in cognitive science, they asked me if it would be possible to show an image (PNG) fullscreen for a couple of milliseconds (10-30 milliseconds).

- My guess is that the framerate of the iPad being around 30 fps, I can go down to around 33 milliseconds… *Does anyone know if it would be possible to go any further?*
- At the moment I'm implementing it using a UIImageview and toggling the visible parameter. *Is there a more effective way of getting the image to show for as short time as possible?*

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: I don't know much about this, but I've heard that a good target framerate for things like scrolling views is 60fps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking to measure subconscious responses to short stimuli, consider something other than an iPad.

The native refresh rate for the iPad 2 is 60Hz, which means that the minimum frame period is 16.67ms. However, you're going to struggle to get an app to translate the "managed" memory into an unmanaged buffer, then present that image buffer to the display, and repeat for the change back, all within 16.67ms. The overheads on the OS, JVM, and the speed of the onboard CPU / memory are just not sufficient. You'd probably only get 25ms (or 40Hz) out of it, if you're lucky.

You *could* achieve the native 60Hz via directly using video, and getting the GPU to do the heavy loading, but with MPEG you're going to run into block encoding issues with single frames like this - the single frame will be garbled into adjacent frames, or the frame would just not get encoded or decoded properly.

There are standard LCD monitors available that support 120Hz, which give you a theoretical minimum frame period of 8.3ms. Given an appropriately written native application on Linux or Windows, you could probably keep the practical time below 10ms, and potentially go as low as 8.5ms. Of course, you'll need a graphics card that natively supports 120Hz display rates.

If you're looking to *really* dig down to ultra-low frame periods, you might need to do some hardware development work. There are a few OLED panels out there that support 200Hz+ refresh rates, primarily for situations where the device will likely be moving (cuts the pan shearing issue) but you won't find them in commercial products - you'll have to build your own display controller to drive one. This is possible via FPGA or a reasonably powerful ARM processor, but will involve a fair bit of knowledge around electronics.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I'll have a look into if I can program my Raspberry Pi's GPU directly in order to get the kind of control I'm looking for. Cheers